# VBA Word - loop through document root elements only?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using VBA on Word and trying to do a task with a simple description:

**Make document content fit on 1 or 2 pages, without leaving a lot of empty space on the last page.**

To do that, I started with one simple step:

Determine total document content height. 
(to later manipulate font size and line spacing according to my needs)

Problem is:

`ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs` lists all paragraphs with no regards to hierarchy. If I have a table in the content, all its contents will be listed, so I can't just use that to infer document content height.

I would like to work over the document structure tree, like

```
doc.header
doc.contents
    paragraph1
    table1
        cell1
            t1c1p1
        cell2
            t1c2p1
            t1c2p2
    paragraph2
    paragraph3
doc.footer
```

And iterate only over the direct children of the content root to get their heights.

But I am having a hard time finding a way to do that. Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: **first suggestion-** you can increase font and check when it causes third page to appear. If so, downsize the font and you get what you need. **second suggestion-** you can loop through paragraphs and check some other parameters of document. E.g. to check if paragraph is inside the table do it in this way: `Activedocument.paragraphs(?).range.tables.count` where result =0 means it is not in the table. **third suggestion-** headers, footers and other parts are separate `storyranges` which you must loop separately.